# Git for website development with single server

Tags: php, mysql, git

I have a website built on `php` and `MySQL` and trying to finally become more organised using `git` for making a distinction between code that is live and code that is still in test. I am the only developer working on the site

I cannot afford having a production and test server. So on the same server I made separate folders, one which is live `/www/live/` and the other that is in development `/www/dev/`.

The development part of the site `/www/dev/` is linked to a sub-domain `dev.mydomain.com`

**Problem 1:** I wish to setup `git` in such a way that my commits go to `/www/dev/` and my pushes go live to `/www/live`. Is it reasonable to do it this way?

**Problem 2:** There are two places in the `/www/dev` code where links to the `MySQL` development database and folders are hard-coded. Commits would work fine, but then pushes would change the live code to now point to development databases and folders. Is there a neat way of managing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No - that's what git branches are for. Create a new branch called develop for all of your dev stuff and push commits to that which you would pull down from `/www/dev`. When ready to go live, merge the develop branch into master and pull master down on `/www/live`
2. Either git ignore the config files or better yet define the environment based on URL, directory path or an environment variable.